# How to set a different image for a node in Bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, bokeh

I understand how to change the size and colour of nodes using the code below

```
graph = GraphRenderer()

# replace the node glyph with an ellipse
# set its height, width, and fill_color
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Ellipse(height=0.1, width=0.2,
                                    fill_color="fill_color")
```

But how to change the glyph of certain nodes or even add an image, for eg: one node might be a user, another a email id , and another a mobile device, Is it possible to represent all of them with a different image or glyph?

Answer (score 0):

One approach for this would be to use a [scatter marker](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/markers.html) which has a `marker` property to parameterize the marker type. The `ColumDataSource` could have a column specifying marker types for each node, or you [`factor_mark`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#mapping-marker-types) to map some categorical value in the data source to a marker type.

Note that you will be limited to the marker types, which can only have sizes specified in screen (pixel) units. If you need something like both rects and ellipses that take data-space units, then Bokeh may not be the most appropriate tool for this use (unless you want to draw all the nodes and edges manually).

Alternatively, it seems possible in principle that you could also use `image_url` for the nodes, so that each node is represented by an image loaded from a specified URL (each node could get a different image URL).